# How to process single update of the resource in given time window

Tags: redis, distributed-system

I am receiving multiple location updates from the device for a particular resource Id . These location updates can be received at an interval of second or milliseconds as well .

I want to process only one of the update for any particular resource Id in a given time window lets say 10 second .

Currently I am reading the last processed request for that resource Id from redis cluster and checking if the time difference is greater than 30 seconds , then only I am processing the request .

Issue happens when we receive the request at almost same time (milliseconds apart) . And two different machine picks those request to process . When both the machine try to get the last processed request for that resource Id , they both get the same record , because of which both the requests enter into the system .

Is there any technique to prevent this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setnx (set if not exists). For resource ID 1, at any timestamp do a division of 10000 (10 seconds). For example, timestamp 1583906206000, the value will be 158390620. And construct the key as resource_1_time_158390620. Till the next 10 secs our key will be the same.

```
setnx resource_1_time_158390620 value
```

If multiple appservers tries, or multiple requests comes within 10 secs, the value will be set for the first one alone. Also this commands returns 1 meaning the value is set and 0 meaning the value is already present. You can make use of it as well.